# vim: search replace with incrementing counter

Tags: vim

What I want to do is execute a search-replace pattern that will include a counter, which keeps track of the number of replacements it has made and numbers them.

Here's an example.  Say I have a code block of the following structure:

```
if (condition1(value)):
  array.push(value)
elseif (condition2(value)):
  array.push(modified(value))
elseif (condition3(value)):
  array.pop(value)
```

But pretend there are like 50 conditions.  I want to put a debug print statement above each `push` or `pop` so that I can see what is happening when it runs.  I can put the same statement before each one with `:%s/^\(\s\+\)\(array.p\)/\1print "DEBUG"\r\1\2/g`, but that isn't helpful because the prints are all the same.

What I'd like is to put `print "DEBUG 1"` before the first match, `print "DEBUG 2"` before the second, etc, but in order to do that, I need some type of counter.

Answer (score 4):

```
:let i = 0|g/\(push\|pop\)/let i = i + 1|put!='print \"DEBUG ' . i . '\"'
```

Explanation:

```
let i = 0                           define a control variable

g/\(push\|pop\)/                    mark all lines containing 'push' or 'pop'
                                    then execute what follows on each marked line

let i = i + 1                       increment the control variable

put!='print \"DEBUG ' . i . '\"'    put the debugging statement above
```

See `:help :global`, `:help :let`, and `:help :put`.